# Protontricks still present after removing

Tags: uninstall, software-uninstall

I removed Protontricks with `sudo apt remove protontricks && sudo apt purge protontricks`, but when I type `protontricks --gui` in terminal, it still displays. Any solutions? Thanks.

EDIT: Fixed it. The package was installed with pipx and I had to remove it using `pipx uninstall protontricks`.

Comment: Try `apt policy protontricks` and see if it comes up with anything.

Comment: @Jos
"protontricks:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.7.0-1
  Version table:
     1.7.0-1 500
        500 http://apt.pop-os.org/ubuntu jammy/multiverse amd64 Packages
        500 http://apt.pop-os.org/ubuntu jammy/multiverse i386 Packages"

EDIT: I apologize, I fixed the problem. The package was installed with pipx and I had to remove it with "pipx uninstall protontricks" command. I'm still a newbie to Linux.

Comment: Only Ubuntu and *official* flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here, refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome if you don't want to use a Pop forum. (*One advantage of Ubuntu is it's many support options, you opted for Pop OS so take advantage of its support options, or SE Unix & Linux* found in the on-topic link)